# Accessing attached "Apple iPhone" in Windows 7 remotely via explorer/file sharing

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, iphone

I'm wondering if it's possible to access an attached "Apple iPhone" device like I would a regular host directory from a Windows 7 box with file sharing turned on.

Normally the syntax would be `\\Host\Folder\` from explorer, but if I try `\\Host\Apple iPhone\` it does not work.

Is there any way to get this working?

Comment: iPhones and other mobile devices do not connect like regular storage. File Explorer will SHOW them like other storage devices, but it is doing "translation" behind the scenes to make things convenient for users. Also, simply turning file sharing on does not share every file/folder/storage device on the hosting computer. The iOS device isn't just another subfolder to your computer and so it isn't part of the file share. I would guess that you cannot turn on file sharing on the iPhone device folders in File Explorer, further illustrating my point.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access an iPhone like a normal directory device, you'll need an app called iFunbox or iMazing. They are their own file viewer, and will continually work over wifi after the device is disconnected.